# Article usage in compound predicate nouns

Tags: articles

When using a compound predicate noun where both parts would normally be preceded by an article, is it correct to leave one article off? Is it correct to use both? Is it a matter of preference? If so, is one way generally preferred over the other?

For instance:

> This book is a help and blessing.

or:

> This book is a help and a blessing.

Comment: I think you should normally repeat the article, but I'd be interested to know if there are any idiomatic "set phrases" where we usually *don't* do that.

Comment: A wash and brush?

Comment: A bow and arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is incorrect, but the latter would be preferred for clarity, since the omission is not efficient enough to justify the change.  The former is a grammatically valid [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) of the second article, i.e. the second article is understood rather than written/spoken.  According to a quick and dirty [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20help%20and%20blessing,a%20help%20and%20a%20blessing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), the two options are close in popularity, with a slight leaning toward retaining both articles.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! And that "Ngram" tool looks to be extremely useful... =)